# DotVvm DataPager not paging

Tags: gridview, datapager, dotvvm

I have a GridView which is bound to a GridViewDataSet.  The grid displays correctly along with the Pager. When you try to change the page an error is thrown in the background and the page does not change.

**View Code**

```
<bs:GridView DataSource="{value: Skus}" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: RecordType}" HeaderText="Category" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: ContourSku}" HeaderText="Contour SKU" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: ProductName}" HeaderText="Product Name" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: CdsCost}" FormatString="c" HeaderText="CDS Cost" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: ListPrice}" FormatString="c" HeaderText="List Price" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: ExtendedMrc}" FormatString="c" HeaderText="MRC" />

        <dot:GridViewTemplateColumn HeaderText="Active" AllowSorting="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <bp:SwitchButton Text="" Checked="{value: IsActive}">
                </bp:SwitchButton>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </dot:GridViewTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</bs:GridView>

<bs:DataPager DataSet="{value: Skus}" />

**ViewModel**
```

```
    [Bind(Direction.ServerToClient)]
    public GridViewDataSet<CloudProductEntity> Skus { get; set; } 

    public override Task Init()
    {
        if (!Context.IsPostBack)
        {
            Skus = new GridViewDataSet<CloudProductEntity>
            {
                PagingOptions = { PageSize = 10 },
                SortingOptions =
                {
                    SortDescending = true,
                    SortExpression = nameof(CloudProductEntity.ContourSku)
                },
            };
            Skus.LoadFromQueryable(CloudProductEntity.Search(Search).AsQueryable());
        }
        return base.Init();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that prevent the paging from working correctly:

1. Unfortunately, `GridViewDataSet` doesn't support one-way bind directions as the paging and sorting parameters are stored in it and need to be submitted to the server.
2. `Init` is not a good place to load data from the database - the recommended way is `PreRender` which happens *after* postback commands. Also, it is better to check whether `DataSet.IsRefreshRequired` than checking on `Context.IsPostBack`, as there may be postbacks that don't require to reload the data.